# how to render csv with a p

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

having trouble getting rails to initiate a csv download

have a form submitting a get to 'send_report.csv'

```
  def send_report
    if Survey.passphrase? params[:passphrase]
      respond_with do |format|
        format.csv{
          report = CSV.generate do |csv|
            csv << ["csv data"]
          end
          send_data report, :type => 'text/csv', :disposition => "attachment", :filename => "file.csv"
        } 
      end
    else
      redirect_to report_path
    end
  end
```

the server seems like everything is wired ok...

```
Started GET "/send_report.csv?utf8=%E2%9C%93&passphrase=123&commit=submit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-12 16:12:19 -0800
Processing by MainController#send_report as CSV
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "passphrase"=>"123", "commit"=>"submit"}
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Sent data file.csv (0.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

but no download interface is appearing in the browser.  I've read the other SO posts on this topic but not seeing the solution.  thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is OK without any problem (Tested carefully). So maybe because of your browser?

Comment: hmm, i def can't get it to work, when you say code is working, you mean the server code or were you actually able to get this to render a download dialogue in the browser ?

Comment: I mean both. Your code works and I actually can get download dialogue in browser (Chrome v31 on Mac OS 10.9). Are you sure that server log is this action log? Could you double check it?

Answer (score 0):

so my problem was that rails jquery mobile gem was inserting some kind of controls onto the page that was messing up the initiation of the csv download, @justin thanks for checking out my code, you were right.